# Reset Total Variable

Tags: c++

I am working on a blackjack-like program. I initially generate a random pair of cards and store the total of the numbers. If the user wishes to, he or she can choose to *play again*. When I compile the program and choose the play again option (enter "n" to the first prompt), the **total** remains the same as the two previously generated random numbers. How do I regenerate random numbers and update the **total** variable?

My code so far:

```cpp
/*
Cortez Phenix
The 25th of January, 2021
CS10B, Mr. Harden
Assignment 2.1

This program uses loops and variables, allowing the user to play a blackjack-like game.
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(nullptr)));

    string card_choice;
    string repeat_choice;
    int num_1 = rand()%10+1;
    int num_2 = rand()%10+1;
    int total = num_1 + num_2;

    do{
        do{
    cout << "\nFirst Cards: " << num_1 << ", " << num_2;
    cout << "\nTotal: " << total << "\n\n";

    do{
    cout << "Do you want another card? (y/n) ";
    cin >> card_choice;
    }
    while (card_choice == "y" && (total += rand()%10+1) && cout << "Total: " << total << "\n\n" && (total != 21) && total < 21);

    if (card_choice == "n"){
            cout << "\nDo you want to play again? (y/n) ";
            cin >> repeat_choice;
            break;

    }

    if (total == 21){
        cout << "Congratulations!\n";
        total = num_1 + num_2;
    }

    if (total > 21){
        cout << "Bust!\n";
        total = num_1 + num_2;
    }

    }
    while (repeat_choice == "y");

    if (repeat_choice == "n"){
        break;
    }
    }
    while (repeat_choice == "y");

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe move the declaration and intialization of `num1`, `num2` and `total` into one of the loops?

Comment: And I removed the irrelevant tags. Tags for specific C++ versions should only be used if the version actually matters, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: there is to much stuff in `main`. If you could split this into small functions (or class with methods) it would be easier to read understand and write new code.

Comment: i personally find `do -while` confusing because the condition is at the bottom. Maybe add a comment after the `do`s, like `this is the game loop` / `choosing more cards` / etc. You want to roll the random numbers each time a new game starts

Comment: proper intendation can also help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: the declaration and initialization of `num1`, `num2` and `total`
should be moved into the first `do-while` loop.

Here's the correct code, also with edited indentations:

```cpp
/*
Cortez Phenix
The 25th of January, 2021
CS10B, Mr. Harden
Assignment 2.1

This program uses loops and variables, allowing the user to play a blackjack-like game.
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(nullptr)));
    string card_choice;
    string repeat_choice;

    do{
        int num_1 = rand()%10+1;
        int num_2 = rand()%10+1;
        int total = num_1 + num_2;


        do{
        cout << "\nFirst Cards: " << num_1 << ", " << num_2;
        cout << "\nTotal: " << total << "\n\n";

            do{
                cout << "Do you want another card? (y/n) ";
                cin >> card_choice;
            }
            while (card_choice == "y" && (total += rand()%10+1) && cout << "Total: " << total << "\n\n" && (total != 21) && total < 21);

        if (card_choice == "n"){
            cout << "\nDo you want to play again? (y/n) ";
            cin >> repeat_choice;
            break;
            }

        if (total == 21){
        cout << "Congratulations!\n";
        total = num_1 + num_2;
    }

        if (total > 21){
        cout << "Bust!\n";
        total = num_1 + num_2;
    }

        }
        while (repeat_choice == "y");

    if (repeat_choice == "n"){
        break;
    }
    }
    while (repeat_choice == "y");

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Here is the completed program, with documentation-

```cpp
/*
Cortez Phenix
The 26th of January, 2021
CS10B, Mr. Harden
Assignment 2.1

This program uses do-while loops, variables, if-then statements, and randomly generated numbers, allowing the user to play a blackjack-like game.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  //Get a different sequence of random numbers each time they need to be generated.
  //Initialize two string variables, later used to allow the user to draw another card or stop playing the game.
  srand(static_cast < unsigned > (time(nullptr)));
  string card_choice;
  string repeat_choice;

  //Main do-while loop that controls game.
  do {
    //Initialize and assign int variables of randomly generated numbers, 1-10. Store the total.
    int num_1 = rand() % 10 + 1;
    int num_2 = rand() % 10 + 1;
    int total = num_1 + num_2;

    //Display the initially-generated first cards and the total.
    do {
      cout << "\nFirst Cards: " << num_1 << ", " << num_2;
      cout << "\nTotal: " << total << "\n\n";

      //Choose new card or not. If yes, generate new number, then update and display the total, provided the total is not equal to or greater than 21.
      do {
        cout << "Do you want another card? (y/n) ";
        cin >> card_choice;
      }
      while (card_choice == "y" && (total += rand() % 10 + 1) && cout << "Total: " << total << "\n\n" && (total != 21) && total < 21);

      //If user does not want another card, prompt for a replay, and exit the loop.
      if (card_choice == "n") {
        cout << "\nDo you want to play again? (y/n) ";
        cin >> repeat_choice;
        break;
      }

      //If the total equals 21, the user wins. Prompt for a replay, and exit the loop.
      if (total == 21) {
        cout << "Congratulations!\n\n";
        cout << "Do you want to play again? (y/n) ";
        cin >> repeat_choice;
        break;
      }

      //If the total is greater than 21, the user loses. Prompt for a replay, and exit the loop.
      if (total > 21) {
        cout << "Bust!\n\n";
        cout << "Do you want to play again? (y/n) ";
        cin >> repeat_choice;
        break;
      }

    }
    //Repeat the game, if the user chooses to.
    while (repeat_choice == "y");

    //Exit the game, if the user chooses to.
    if (repeat_choice == "n") {
      break;
    }

  }
  //Repeat the game, if the user chooses to.
  while (repeat_choice == "y");

  return 0;
}
```